# You love me, but you hit me

Tags: riddle

> Some Asians like me, but some don't.
>   Truth is I usually just get in the way.
>   The Americans might get me soon, but I will have to be shared.
>   Unfortunately, the people who will share will probably hate me.
>   Some say I can hear things, but obviously I can't.
>   An unconventional hero loves me, but always hits me.

Who am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're talking about a

> Wall

"Some Asians like me, but some don't"

> Great Wall of China?

"Truth is, I usually just get in the way"

> Self explanatory

"The Americans might get me soon, but I will have to be shared."
"Unfortunately, the people who will share will probably hate me."

> Donald Trump's proposed wall, shared with Mexico

"Some say I can hear things, but obviously I can't."

> Often used phrase about walls hearing things

"An unconventional hero loves me, but always hits me. "

> Deadpool? (Breaking the fourth wall)

Comment: Hero = Mario? :)

Comment: +1 I guess my riddle was too easy again XD. I'm giving the win to the one who can figure out the hero though. Which is not Mario.

Comment: The saying is "Walls have ears". Could the unconventional hero be the ball in Breakout?

Comment: @JonathanAllan I don't know what that is, but the hero will be much more mainstream than that.

Comment: @stackreader just [a classic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakout_(video_game))

Comment: @stackreader Updated guess for the last line.

Comment: Bingo! Good job!

Comment: @stackreader haha A film that passed me by unnoticed and a phrase of which I was unaware. I guess I'm just not mainstream :p

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> a Wall ?
>  - Asians like me -> Great wall of China
>  - Wall gets in the way .
>  - Americans may get a wall due to Trump.
>  - Walls can hear things but they actually can't.
>  - Hero -> Mario (Suggested by @Techidiot)

Comment: Who do you suppose is the "hero"?

Comment: Not sure. Sorry. A video game character maybe.

Comment: Hero = mario? :)

Comment: Mario ... Would those platforms be wall ? I suppose so.

Comment: Wild guess.. Hero refers to Heroes from David Bowie..Song refers to Berlin Wall.